# Why does Ruby keeps code evaluation after throwing a NameError exception?

Tags: ruby

Simple code which I can not explain to myself:

```
puts a if a = 1
```

This results in

```
warning: found = in conditional, should be ==
NameError: undefined local variable or method 'a' for main:Object
```

Though, now upon checking `a` we can see, that it has been defined:

```
a #=> 1
```

Why does `a` get assigned to `1` despite the exception thrown?

From the [docs](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Local+Variables+and+Methods):

> The confusion comes from the **out-of-order execution of the expression**.
>   First the local variable is assigned-to then you attempt to call a
>   nonexistent method [`a`].

This part is still confusing - why does interpreter not detecting *already defined* local variable `a` and still tries to call a "nonexisting" method? Should it not check for local variables as well, find defined local variable `a` and print `1`?

Comment: FYI: both `puts eval('a') if a = 1` and `puts binding.local_variable_get(:a) if a = 1` do work as you would expect. Seems like the current implementation is either a shortcoming or some kind of optimization. It certainly _could_ be implemented that way.

Comment: From doc `Rather than printing “true” you receive a NameError, “undefined local variable or method 'a'”. Since ruby parses the bare a left of the if first and has not yet seen an assignment to a it assumes you wish to call a method. Ruby then sees the assignment to a and will assume you are referencing a local method.` This makes sense because when `if a = 1` is being evaluated, it doesn't know it is a local variable yet, so it calls out `a` as a method - which of course doesn't exists hence the exception.

Comment: Regarding your question why `a` is `1` despite the exception: that's because the  `NameError` is raised by `puts a`, not by `if a = 1`. The assignment succeeds and then the method call fails.

Comment: @CarySwoveland tried both your examples in `irb` and `pry` REPLs before posting the question - both resulted in the same `NameError` exception.

Comment: @Surya you say `"it doesn't know it is a local variable yet"` - why if the expression on the right of the `if` (`a = 1`) was evaluated first?

Comment: @Stefan thank you very much for both of your comments - both are really useful and interesting! Can I ask about "shortcoming" term you used - do you mean REPL is failing to "properly" work? Cause at this point I am still not sure whether my assumption that `a` should have not only beeen checked within list of defined local methods but also in the list of defined local variables is correct... Also, first paragrapg of @Jorg's answers makes it farther confusing having what you showed

Comment: @AndreyDeineko the local variable does exist when executing the code and you can retrieve its value dynamically. You just cannot reference it statically because the parser treats it as a method call. (see my answer)

Comment: Andrey, I forgot to restart IRB. (Dumb.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's take a look at Ruby's abstract syntax tree for modifier `if`:

```
$ ruby --dump=parsetree -e 'puts a if a = 1'

# @ NODE_SCOPE (line: 1, code_range: (1,0)-(1,15))
# +- nd_tbl: :a
# +- nd_args:
# |   (null node)
# +- nd_body:
#     @ NODE_PRELUDE (line: 1, code_range: (1,0)-(1,15))
#     +- nd_head:
#     |   (null node)
#     +- nd_body:
#     |   @ NODE_IF (line: 1, code_range: (1,0)-(1,15))
#     |   +- nd_cond:
#     |   |   @ NODE_DASGN_CURR (line: 1, code_range: (1,10)-(1,15))
#     |   |   +- nd_vid: :a
#     |   |   +- nd_value:
#     |   |       @ NODE_LIT (line: 1, code_range: (1,14)-(1,15))
#     |   |       +- nd_lit: 1
#     |   +- nd_body:
#     |   |   @ NODE_FCALL (line: 1, code_range: (1,0)-(1,6))
#     |   |   +- nd_mid: :puts
#     |   |   +- nd_args:
#     |   |       @ NODE_ARRAY (line: 1, code_range: (1,5)-(1,6))
#     |   |       +- nd_alen: 1
#     |   |       +- nd_head:
#     |   |       |   @ NODE_VCALL (line: 1, code_range: (1,5)-(1,6))
#     |   |       |   +- nd_mid: :a
#     |   |       +- nd_next:
#     |   |           (null node)
#     |   +- nd_else:
#     |       (null node)
#     +- nd_compile_option:
#         +- coverage_enabled: false
```

And for standard `if`:

```
$ ruby --dump=parsetree -e 'if a = 1 then puts a end'

# @ NODE_SCOPE (line: 1, code_range: (1,0)-(1,24))
# +- nd_tbl: :a
# +- nd_args:
# |   (null node)
# +- nd_body:
#     @ NODE_PRELUDE (line: 1, code_range: (1,0)-(1,24))
#     +- nd_head:
#     |   (null node)
#     +- nd_body:
#     |   @ NODE_IF (line: 1, code_range: (1,0)-(1,24))
#     |   +- nd_cond:
#     |   |   @ NODE_DASGN_CURR (line: 1, code_range: (1,3)-(1,8))
#     |   |   +- nd_vid: :a
#     |   |   +- nd_value:
#     |   |       @ NODE_LIT (line: 1, code_range: (1,7)-(1,8))
#     |   |       +- nd_lit: 1
#     |   +- nd_body:
#     |   |   @ NODE_FCALL (line: 1, code_range: (1,14)-(1,20))
#     |   |   +- nd_mid: :puts
#     |   |   +- nd_args:
#     |   |       @ NODE_ARRAY (line: 1, code_range: (1,19)-(1,20))
#     |   |       +- nd_alen: 1
#     |   |       +- nd_head:
#     |   |       |   @ NODE_DVAR (line: 1, code_range: (1,19)-(1,20))
#     |   |       |   +- nd_vid: :a
#     |   |       +- nd_next:
#     |   |           (null node)
#     |   +- nd_else:
#     |       (null node)
#     +- nd_compile_option:
#         +- coverage_enabled: false
```

The only difference is the method argument for `puts`:

```
#     |   |       |   @ NODE_VCALL (line: 1, code_range: (1,5)-(1,6))
#     |   |       |   +- nd_mid: :a
```

vs:

```
#     |   |       |   @ NODE_DVAR (line: 1, code_range: (1,19)-(1,20))
#     |   |       |   +- nd_vid: :a
```

With modifier `if`, the parser treats `a` as a method call and creates a `NODE_VCALL`. This instructs the interpreter to make a method call (although there *is* a local variable `a`), resulting in a `NameError`. (because there is no method `a`)

With standard `if`, the parser treats `a` as a local variable and creates a `NODE_DVAR`. This instructs the interpreter to look up a local variable which works as expected.

As you can see, Ruby recognizes local variables at the parser level. That's why the documentation says: (emphasis added)

> the modifier and standard versions [...] are not exact transformations of each other **due to parse order**.

Comment: Possibly some of the confusion here comes from the generic exception message, `undefined local variable or method 'a'`. This message is accurate almost all the time; typically when this error is raised, neither the method or variable `a` exists. However, in this odd case, `a` is already decided to be a method invocation before the local variable exists, but the same type of exception is raised with the same generic error regardless, so we wind up with this slightly misleading error message.

Comment: @meagar yes, indeed. Although the error message could be read as _"you can define a local variable `a` or a method `a` in order to fix it"_ which is both true. Or to put it another way: it would just be as misleading if you could fix a `NoMethodError` by defining a local variable.

Comment: @Stefan, man, can't describe how awesome, precise and complete your answer is! This AST is unfortunately absolutely unreadable for me, but your text explanation is simply perfect. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Ruby parses code left-to-right. Local variables get defined when the first assignment to them is being parsed. At `puts a`, no assignment to `a` has been parsed yet, thus the local variable `a` doesn't exist yet, and Ruby assumes `a` is a method call. The local variable only exists to the *right* and *below* the assignment.

At runtime, Ruby has to evaluate the condition in order to figure out whether to execute the `puts`, so `a` gets initialized to `1`.

You seem to be executing that code within some kind of REPL. Usually, REPLs rescue exceptions instead of terminating, which is why your code keeps executing instead of terminating, and since we are now below the assignment, the variable is defined, and since the assignment was executed, the variable is initialized.

If the distinction between *definition* and *initialization* of a variable is unclear to you, meditate on this:

```
foo
# NameError

if false
  foo = 42
end

foo
#=> nil

foo = :bar

foo
#=> :bar
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, @Jörg. The very first paragraph of your answer clicked that for me... BUT then what about @Stefan's comment: `puts eval('a') if a = 1` where it "properly" prints `1`? Same goes with `puts binding.local_variable_get(:a) if a = 1` - why then these two result in `1` printed even though both should have failed due to that first paragraph of the answers of yours.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko Stefan's AST answer made this click for me. By the time `puts a` is evaluated, the parser has already decided that `a` is a method invocation. The problem is compounded by the overly generic error message for `NameError`, *"undefined local variable or method 'a'"*. This message implies that Ruby looked for an did not find a local variable `a`, when in actuality the *parser* already decided that `a` is a method. The presence of a local *variable* `a` was not considered at the time the exception was raised, though the exception's message (wrongly) states otherwise.

Comment: Conversely, with `eval('a')`, nothing within the string to be `eval`'d has been decided by the parser yet, and when it is parsed, the newly defined local variable `a` can be found, and `a` will be parsed as variable, not a method invocation. Interestingly we can "prove" (as though we needed to) that Ruby's AST is accurate by defining `a` as a method, rather than a local variable, meaning the method invocation that parser assumed to exist actually will. Running `puts a if define_method(:a) { 1 }` works fine, and prints `1` without a `NameError`.